# Как выполнить сортировку многомерного массива по одному полю?

Tags: php, сортировка

Здравствуйте. Есть массив:

```
array(3)=>
    array(2)=>
        'count'=10;
        'value'="some string";
    array(2)=>
        'count'=100;
        'value'="another string";
    array(2)=>
        'count'=2;
        'value'="last string";
```

Я хочу выполнить сортировку по ключу 'count', чтобы получить на выходе такой массив:

```
array(3)=>
    array(2)=>
        'count'=100;
        'value'="another string";
    array(2)=>
        'count'=10;
        'value'="some string";
    array(2)=>
        'count'=2;
        'value'="last string";
```

Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: @Visman таких дубликатов на неделе по два тут появляються...

Comment: @Naumov, предлагаю все дубликаты пометить ;)

Comment: @Visman Их уже раз 100 каждый пометил :D даже на мете была тема на это тему уж простите за туфтологию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['count'] == $b['count']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['count'] < $b['count']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$myArray = array(...);

usort($myArray, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте мощь функций сортировки, использующих заданный алгоритм сравнения.

```
$arr = [
    [
        'count' => 10,
        'value' => 'some string'
    ], [
        'count' => 100,
        'value' => 'another string'
    ], [
        'count' => 2,
        'value' => 'last string'
    ]
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return $b['count'] <=> $a['count'];
});
```

https://repl.it/D90r

P. S. Оператор Spaceship доступен с PHP 7. Заменить легко, если нужно, как - домашнее задание :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так, но ответ выше более компактней и удобнее

```
$arr = array(
array(
    'count' => '10',
    'name'  => 'some string'
),
array(
    'count' => '100',
    'name'  => 'some 2string'
),
array(
    'count' => '526',
    'name'  => 'some 3string'
)
);


for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
  for ($j=0; $j < count($arr); $j++) { 
    $count = $arr[$j]['count'];
    $next_count = $arr[$j+1]['count'];

    if($count < $next_count){
        $temp = $next_count;

        $arr[$j+1]['count'] = $count;
        $arr[$j]['count']   = $temp;
    }
  }
}
```

**Результат**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 526
        [name] => some string
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [count] => 100
        [name] => some 2string
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [count] => 10
        [name] => some 3string
    )

)
```

Comment: [Коан про ваш ответ](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/151?lang=ru).